# Android Studio how to get versionNameSuffix in code

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, version

In my Gradle file I declare the VersionName and VersionCode like

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.0"
    versionNameSuffix ".alpha1"
    setProperty("archivesBaseName", "MyApp.$versionName.$versionCode$versionNameSuffix")
    signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

and in my application I can retreive the versionCode and versionName with

```
applicationInformation.VERSIONNAME = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
applicationInformation.VERSIONCODE = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
```

But how can I get the versionNameSuffix?  There isn't a field in BuildConfig for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` contains the concatenation of `versionName` and `versionNameSuffix` like :

```
public static final String VERSION_NAME = "0.71.alpha1";
```

If you need only the `versionNameSuffix`, you can create a new BuildConfig variable in your `build.gradle` like this :

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "VERSION_NAME_SUFFIX", "\"" + defaultConfig.versionNameSuffix + "\""
    }

    release {
        buildConfigField "String", "VERSION_NAME_SUFFIX", "\"" + defaultConfig.versionNameSuffix + "\""
    }
}
```

You can now get `VERSION_NAME_SUFFIX` from `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME_SUFFIX` which features :

```
public static final String VERSION_NAME_SUFFIX = ".alpha1";
```